# Is it thread safe when one thread add timer to boost::asio::io_service and the other is running io_service::run at the same time?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, boost-asio

To make long story short, my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
namespace bp = boost::posix_time;

typedef std::map<int, ba::deadline_timer*> timer_map;

timer_map g_timers;
boost::mutex g_timers_lock;

ba::io_service g_ios;

void on_timer(int id) {
    {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(g_timers_lock);
            timer_map::iterator it = g_timers.find(id);
            assert(it != g_timers.end());
            g_timers.erase(id);
    }

    // std::cout << "delete timer " << id << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
    boost::thread trd(boost::bind(&ba::io_service::run, &g_ios));
    trd.detach();

    int count = 0;
    for (;;) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    ba::deadline_timer* pt = new ba::deadline_timer(g_ios, bp::seconds(1));
                    pt->async_wait(boost::bind(&on_timer, count));

                    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(g_timers_lock);
                    g_timers.insert(std::make_pair(count++, pt));
            }

            usleep(20000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

==================================

I know, I should lock the g_timers, but should I lock the g_ios?
I mean these lines:

```
ba::deadline_timer* pt = new ba::deadline_timer(g_ios, bp::seconds(1));
pt->async_wait(boost::bind(&on_timer, count));
```

Are thread safety? It reference the g_ios, and will it call g_ios.add_job(this_timer) ..etc.. ?

Comment: +1 for the [reproducer](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to directly answer your question, yes an instance of an `io_service` is thread safe. This is described in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html).

> ### *Thread Safety*
>
> **Distinct objects**: Safe.
>
> **Shared objects**: Safe, with the specific exceptions of the `reset()` and
>   `notify_fork()` functions. Calling reset() while there are unfinished
>   `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` calls results in undefined
>   behaviour. The `notify_fork()` function should not be called while any
>   `io_service` function, or any function on an I/O object that is
>   associated with the `io_service`, is being called in another thread.

Though, it's not obvious to me what you're attempting to accomplish. As written, your example accomplishes nothing because the `io_service` has no work to do when you invoke `io_service::run()` so it returns immediately. You ignored the [return value](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html), I suspect if you inspected it, it would be zero.

Your use of mutexes is also questionable. In general, if you need access to a shared resource from within an asynchronous handler, prefer to use a [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) instead of a mutex. This concept is discussed quite well in the Asio examples and [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html), as is the use of [threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html).

Comment: Thanks advance! I still have some doubts. "...io_service::run so it returns immediately"  --I debug the program by gdb and uncomment the line "std::cout << "delete timer" << id << std::endl;" , the thread was return immediately but the line "delete timer"[id] was printed, and many times. I can't find why the thread return and the callback function was called.

Comment: Thanks, I found that why "the io_service::run return" and my callback function "on_timer" was called. Because the io_service::run was not really return immediately, I slept 1 second before add timer to the io_service, and there was no "delete timer".. printed. Thanks!

Comment: @user1105178 I think you're missing the point. You shouldn't need to `sleep()` prior to running your `io_service`. That in itself is a non-deterministic operation. You need to give your `io_service` some work to do before running it, then add additional work in the asynchronous handlers as needed.